# EXcel use of BDP and BDH function

Tags: excel, add-in, bloomberg

I want to retrive data from a past date about VOLUME_AVG_30D. Can I? I just could use the BDP to retrive this data and then this just give me the last update about this information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, that's what the excel adding does. Just go to the formula builder on the ribbon in the excel add-in.  If you need history, use bdh.

```
Formula: =BDH(security, field(s), start date, end date)

Sample: =BDH($B$6,$C$7:$C$7,"12/23/2016","","Dir=V","Dts=S","Sort=A","Quote=C","QtTyp=Y","Days=T","Per=cd","DtFmt=D","UseDPDF=Y","CshAdjNormal=N","CshAdjAbnormal=N","CapChg=N","cols=2;rows=102")
```

Comment: I tried it but doesn't work. It says that there is an inalid field. But with BDP it works well. This happens only with this data type.

Comment: Edited the answer, try this as an example, should work:  
  
  =BDH($B$6,$C$7:$C$7,"12/23/2016","","Dir=V","Dts=S","Sort=A","Quote=C","QtTyp=Y","Days=T","Per=cd","DtFmt=D","UseDPDF=Y","CshAdjNormal=N","CshAdjAbnormal=N","CapChg=N","cols=2;rows=102")

Comment: I tried it already. Now I know that this data can't be retrieved with BDH, only BDP. I asked to bloomberg help desk.