# Download historical data from a list of ISIN on Bloomberg

Tags: bloomberg

I want to download historical data (mid dirty price on daily frequency) for a list of ISIN (bonds) that I have as a CSV file, for the period 2016-2023. How can I download them? Idk how to put the ISIN list in the bloomberg add-in

To get data for 2016-2023 period for

Comment: How to use ISINs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080470/bloomberg-bdh-function-with-isin
How to use BDH: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44119844/excel-use-of-bdp-and-bdh-function